# Bash posix regex optional groups

Tags: bash, regular-expression, posix

Trying to match some Gentoo package naming components from strings in forms category/name-version, due to its complexity, I have come to this:

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ^([<>]?=?)(([^\/]+)\/)?([^[:space:]]+)-(([[:digit:]]+)?(\.([[:digit:]]+))*([a-z])?(_(alpha|beta|pre|rc|p)([[:digit:]]*))*(-(r([[:digit:]]+))?)?)?$ ]]; then
    # use "${BASH_REMATCH[n]}" here to capture groups contents
fi
```

It splits strings like `<category/package-name-12345.25b_rc10-r7` as expected:

```
Version specifier: <
Category: category
Package name: package-name
Version: 12345.25b_rc10-r7
Version, major: 12345
Version, minor: 25
Version, letter: b
Version, patch type: rc
Version, patch level: 10
Version, revision number: 7
```

Now, I need to match and split stings that may have version missing, like `category/package-name`.

So, is there a way to make the version part above optional?

Above, this part is the following:

```
-(([[:digit:]]+)?(\.([[:digit:]]+))*([a-z])?(_(alpha|beta|pre|rc|p)([[:digit:]]*))*(-(r([[:digit:]]+))?)?)?
```

I've tried to change it as:

```
(-(([[:digit:]]+)?(\.([[:digit:]]+))*([a-z])?(_(alpha|beta|pre|rc|p)([[:digit:]]*))*(-(r([[:digit:]]+)))?))?
```

It works for a string without a version, but there seem that optional groups prevent it to match a slightly complete string like above and it gets:

```
Version specifier: 
Category: category
Package name: package-name-12345.25b_rc10-r7
Version: 
Version, major: 
Version, minor: 
Version, letter: 
Version, patch type: 
Version, patch level: 
Version, revision number:
```

**EDIT:** Slots

What about two optional parts?

Additionally to the above, must match slots.
Slots would be matched like this:

`:(([[:digit:]]+)(\.([[:digit:]]+))*)?`

Now, there are a category/name part:

`([<>]?=?)(([^\/]+)\/)?([^[:space:]]+)`

followed by either a version:
`-(([[:digit:]]+)(\.([[:digit:]]+))*)([a-z])?(_(alpha|beta|pre|rc|p)([[:digit:]]*))*(-(r([[:digit:]]+))?)?`

a slot
`:(([[:digit:]]+)(\.([[:digit:]]+))*)?`

or both, version and slot, in this order.

Note, a version starts with the `-`, as separator, and a slot starts with the `:`, as separator.

All I can think of is:

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ^${CATEGORY_PACKAGE}-${VERSION}:${SLOT}$ ]] ; then
    # use "${BASH_REMATCH[n]}" here to capture groups contents
else
    if [[ "$1" =~ ^${CATEGORY_PACKAGE}:${SLOT}$ ]] ; then
        # use "${BASH_REMATCH[n]}" here to capture groups contents
    else
        if [[ "$1" =~ ^${CATEGORY_PACKAGE}-${VERSION}$ ]] || [[ "$1" =~ ^${CATEGORY_PACKAGE}$ ]] ; then
        # use "${BASH_REMATCH[n]}" here to capture groups contents
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Is this a full solution?
Is there a better version?
Is there a POSIX solution based on options, like `<category-name>(<slot option>|<version option>|<version:slot> option)`?

**EDIT:**

I think bash can handle optional groups in one expression, but I fail to change `([^[:space:]:]+)` to handle a `hyphen`. How can `hyphen` be included as does not seem to work neither as the first, nor the last in the range?

Comment: Say the input was `foo-bar-2022`, is `2022` a version or part of the name of the package?

Comment: I'd consider it a version number, there are packages like this. Generally, the package string has also a category, so would be like `foo-category/foo-bar-2022`, but to work without categories would be a plus. As a rule, versions are separated by the name by a `-`.

Comment: re. that edit, if you have another question, post another question.

Comment: `[^-[:space:]:]` or `[^[:space:]:-]` work to match any character except whitespace, colon and hyphen but since your package names can apparently contain `-`s, it's probably not an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the sake of sanity, in situations like this, IMO it's better to just use multiple regular expressions instead of stuffing every possible situation into a single regex:

```
base_package_name_regex='^([<>]?=?)(([^/]+)/)?([^[:space:]]+)'
version_regex='(([[:digit:]]+)?(\.([[:digit:]]+))*([a-z])?(_(alpha|beta|pre|rc|p)([[:digit:]]*))*(-(r([[:digit:]]+))?)?)?$ '
if [[ "$1" =~ $base_package_name_regex-$version_regex ]] || # package with version number
    [[ "$1" =~ $base_package_name_regex ]]  #  package without version number

then
    # use "${BASH_REMATCH[n]}" here to capture groups contents
fi
```

Also note that in POSIX ERE, what `\/` matches is unspecified and `[^\/]` matches any character other than backslash or slash. I've removed those spurious backslashes.

Comment: I agree, basically, I've just needed a way to write it to detect and handle the same situation even in working per parts, like splitting it first in category, name and version strings. There I've failed too, so I have put here the entire problem to be clear the requirement. Hopefully..

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use a shell, you could switch to `zsh`. Then you can use PCREs instead of POSIX EREs with which

- you get non-greedy operators which you need here for `[^[:space:]]+` (which we can shorten to `\S+` in PCRE and which we change to the non-greedy `\S+?` variant) not to gobble everything up to the end leaving no chance for the version to be matched
- you can make the regexp more legible with `(?x)`
- capture only what you need to capture (using `(?: ...)` for non-capturing groups).

```
set -o rematchpcre
field_names=(
  version_specifier
  category
  package
  version
  major
  minor
  letter
  patch_type
  patch_level
  revision
)

typeset -A fields

if [[ $1 =~ '(?x)
  ^
  (?<version_specifier> [<>]? =? )
  (?: (?<category> [^/]+ ) / )?
  (?<package> \S+? )
  (?:
    -
    (?<version>
      (?<major> \d* )
      (?: \. (?<minor> \d+ ) )*
      (?<letter> [a-z] )?
      (?:
    _(?<patch_type> alpha|beta|pre|rc|p )
    (?<patch_level> \d* )
      )*
      (?: - (?: r (?<revision> \d+ ) )? )?
    )?
  )?
  \z' ]]; then
  fields=( "${(@)field_names:^match}" )
  typeset -p fields
fi
```

Note that we name the capture groups here with `(?<name> ...)` but that's only for documentation purposes, the capture groups are stored in the simple `$match` array, zsh doesn't support retrieving them by name like the `%+{name}` of `perl`.

Here that script gives:

```
$ ./that-script '<category/package-name-12345.25b_rc10-r7'
typeset -A fields=(
 [category]=category
 [letter]=b
 [major]=12345
 [minor]=25
 [package]=package-name
 [patch_level]=10
 [patch_type]=rc
 [revision]=7
 [version]=12345.25b_rc10-r7
 [version_specifier]='<'
)
$ ./that-script '<category/package-name'
typeset -A fields=(
 [category]=category
 [package]=package-name
 [version_specifier]='<'
)
$ ./that-script package-name
typeset -A fields=(
 [category]=''
 [package]=package-name
 [version_specifier]=''
)
```

Comment: Indeed, `zsh` is great, but not an option for me right now.

Comment: How about perl, python or other proper programming language?

Comment: Sorry, bash only.